# Sign in popup on checkout even after user is logged in

Tags: magento2, customer-account, magento2.3.0

I'm having this issue with Magento 2.3.0. 
When the user logs in to their account and adds products to cart. They click "Proceed to Checkout" either in Cart page and the Login/Signup popup shows. However the user is already logged in. I've disabled all of my modules and tried different themes and it still occurs.

[image]

Comment: I'm running into this issue as wel...

Comment: @MrPeanutbutter Any solution?